# Android decompiler inserts 'this' keyword everywhere in the code?

Tags: java, android, this

I have original code which is given below.But i tried decompiling original apk it gave me this keyword everywhere(shown after this code below) :

```
public class Aboutt extends Activity {

WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aboutt);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);




    if (savedInstanceState != null)
        web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    else
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        }
```

**But the decompiled code gives me:**

```
public class Aboutt
extends Activity {
ProgressBar progressBar;
WebView web;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_aboutt);
this.web = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview01));
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
this.web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
} else {
this.web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
this.progressBar = (ProgressBar)this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
this.web.setWebViewClient((WebViewClient)new myWebClient());
this.web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
this.web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

Here it gives this everywhere.
Will it affect working of the app or can i use this everywehere.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class i.e. the object that the method is called on.

Usually, `this` is omitted because if you have something like this:

```
private int i;
public int getI () { return i}
```

everyone knows that you are referring to `i`. If you want to add the `this` keyword, it's just more wordy and will not affect the compiled code.

Whenever you see your code reference a non-static member, you can add the `this` suffix. Like in the above example, you can change `i` to `this.i`.

However, `this` does not work in a static method. I mean it will ***NEVER*** appear in a static context.

But other than that, `this` is fine to appear anywhere else.

Comment: Yes of course! An Android app is just another Java program. @SanDarv

Answer (score -1):

`this` is a reference to the **current instance** of a class. It is mostly used un cases where there are similar names of parameters and local variables (they live as long as the method) and member variables (which live as long as the object).

So while it's not okay to use it ***everywhere*** (will not work in static context for instance) you're safe with what the decompiler created.

Comment: So has the decompiler created 'this' correctly in my ANdroid code and can the decompiled Android code  work fully(apart from static context)? @Jan

Comment: Yes looks fine. Merry Xmas

Comment: Merry Xmas @Jan and does the Android decompiler create this keyword in static method or skips them

Comment: It will not create in static context.

Comment: @SanDarv Of course it will! Complexity does not matter! As long as it is working correctly.

Comment: So if Android uses java then 'this' keyword should work properly in the code of Android app? @Jan

Comment: @Sweeper - `this` does not affect complexity.  Just readability.